# Recreating a Sentence from a list of its words(no repeats) and positions

Tags: python-3.x

```
String = "ask not what your country can do for you ask"
words = ["ask","not","what","your","country","can","do","for","you","ask"]
positions = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,1]
```

I need to recreate the original String with the words and positions. It cannot refer back to the original String

```
String = "ask not what your country can do for you ask"
words = ["ask","not","what","your","country","can","do","for","you","ask"]
positions = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,1]

for word in String():
   if not word in words:
      words.append(word)
   i = words.index(word)
   positions.append(i)

s = "" 
for i in positions:
   s = s + words[i] + " "

print(s)
```

I can recreate the Sentence but I have to use the original String

Comment: It has to be recreate through the unique words and positions

Comment: Are you sure you had your variable `words` correct? That does not seem to correspond with what you say. Also, what did you try to solve the problem?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! All that has been posted is a program description. However, we need you to [ask a question](//stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). Stack Overflow is not a free code writing service. Please [edit] your post to include a valid question that we can answer. Reminder: make sure you know [what is on-topic here](//stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic), asking us to write the program for you and suggestions are off-topic.

Comment: "Please do my homework for me" is not a good Stack Overflow
question.  If you [edit] your question to describe what you
have tried so far and where you are stuck, then we can try
to help you to understand your specific problem. You should
also read [ask].

Answer (score 0):

This answers:

```
String = "ask not what your country can do for you ask"
words = String
list_word = String.split()
res=[]
dict_word={}
for i, j in enumerate(list_word):
    if j in dict_word:
        res.append(dict_word[j])
    else:
        dict_word[j]=i
        res.append(i)
print words
print res


ask not what your country can do for you ask
[0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 0]
```